# Django delete item use case : good practice?

Tags: python, django

Little general explanation.
I'm pretty newbie in Django, I have a little knowledge, but nothing as experience. The code that I want ask about is working, but I have a question about good/bad practice. Does my approach is good or at least not bad?

Little use case explanation.
I have a site with the items. There is a functionality to add the items and now I want to add a possibility to delete the item.
Use case : on the page of item user clicks on the button Delete, we will show a page with details about this item and the button "Confirm delete" at the bottom. If user click on the button I delete this item from database.

So

1. I create in **urls.py**

`path('item/delete/<int:id>/', views.delete_item, {}, 'delete_item'),`

2. I create in **views.py**

```
def delete_item(request,id):
    if id :
        cur_item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=id)
    else : 
        raise Http404

    if request.POST:
        try :
            post_item_id=int(request.POST["pk"])
        except ValueError :
            messages.error(request,"Wrong id number")
            return render(request, 'myapp/item_delete_form.html', {'cur_item': cur_item})

        if (request.POST["delete"] == "yes") and (post_item_id == id):

            Item.objects.filter(pk=id).delete()
            # Delete was successful, so redirect to another page
            redirect_url = reverse('items')
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "id number in form not the same as in URL")
            return render(request, 'myapp/item_delete_form.html', {'cur_item' : cur_item})

    return render(request, 'myapp/item_delete_form.html', {'cur_item' : cur_item})
```

3. I do not use Django Forms as for me it's not the real Django form (i.e. it's not linked to a Model).  As mention by @akx in the comments I could always create a Form based directly on forms.Form. But it seems also useless for me as in fact there is almost no data in my form.
   Instead I just create generic form in the template.
   In **templates/myapp/item_delete_form.html**

First part of template get cur_item and show it. And then :

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ cur_item.id }}" name="pk">
   <input class="btn btn-default btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit" value="yes"/>
</form>
```

4. Finally here the small test to check it :

```
def test_delete_item(self):
     test_serial = "111-111"
     new_item = Item(serial_number=test_serial)
     new_item.save()

     url = reverse("delete_item", kwargs={'id':new_item.id})
     resp = self.client.get(url)
     confirm_data = {'pk': new_item.id,'delete': 'yes'}
     resp = self.client.post(url, confirm_data)
     self.assertEqual(Item.objects.all().count(), 0)
```

Whilst I'll be very appreciate to have and comments about my realisation, here are some practical questions.

Does the practice to analyze request.POST list is not the "bad practice"?
As I do not use Django forms I could not do form.is_valid. Is it ok?

Are there some pitfalls that I should think about (for example does user have the rights to delete this item, but for the moment user system is not developed so I could do nothing about that)?

Does my test is relevant?

And finally, if my realization is not a good or acceptable practice, how should I do my use case ?

Comment: "not the real Django form (i.e. it's not linked to a Model)" You do know `forms.Form` forms aren't linked to models? Only `forms.ModelForm`s are...

Comment: Thank for comment. Yes, I know it and my first attempt was to create a generic Form based on forms.Form... But finally I found that it's a little bit useless as there is almost nothing in my form. Globally it's just a button (and hidden field with id).

Comment: @PaulZakharov I would like to ask why you have this `post_item_id=int(request.POST["pk"])`? Why do you post the id when it is _already_ present in the url, appears some what redundant to me and also looks like one can then delete some object by posting its id while the url refers to some other object.

Comment: @abdul-aziz-barkat Thank you. Indeed it seems not necessary. Just to explain why I wrote it. May be there were two reasons : 1) at first I start coding using generic forms.Form and there was a "pk" in this form. Then I found that the Form is unnecessary, so I dropped it, but "pk" stayed. 2) second reason : may be in future I'd like add a possibility to remove several items so we should be able to remove items based on there's "pk". But effectively in my actual realization "pk" is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save yourself quite some trouble by just using Django's default [`DeleteView` CBV](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/):

### urls.py

```
path('item/delete/<int:pk>/', DeleteItemView.as_view(), name='delete_item'),
```

### views.py

```
class DeleteItemView(DeleteView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "myapp/item_delete_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('items')
```

### item_delete_form.html

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input class="btn btn-default btn-danger" name="delete" type="submit" value="yes" />
</form>
```

---

In fact, you don't even necessarily need a `views.py`. Just setting the arguments for the CBV in `urls.py` would do...

```
path(
    "item/delete/<int:pk>/",
    DeleteView.as_view(
        model=Item,
        template_name="myapp/item_delete_form.html",
        success_url=reverse_lazy("items"),
    ),
    name="delete_item",
)
```

would be equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution seems very optimal for my use case and I'll probably adopt it. 
Still a very little question about my realization (just to understand). It's evident that it's not optimal and not clean as solution, but do you see any pitfall that made it dangerous.

Comment: There's nothing specially dangerous (aside from the fact that you have no `@login_required` or any other authentication) in there. Just you're doing a lot of manual work you shouldn't.

Comment: Small update.  Finally I think the second option (using only urls.py) do not fulfill all the functionality as it does not pass cur_item to the template to show it. In my I did it here : ```render(request, 'myapp/item_delete_form.html', {'cur_item' : cur_item})```. Still it seems that using views.py I could easily do it.

Comment: My bad. ```context_object_name = 'name_to_use_in_template' ``` do perfectly the job.